# XUnit.net global runners

Tags: c#, testing, xunit.net

According to this issue page XUnit supports global custom test runners.
https://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9722

However I did not found any info about how to configure it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is fixed, but probably not in the way that might be expected.

The original issue asked for support related to an xUnit.net v1.x feature (`ITestCommand` and `ITestClassCommand`). The actual feature that was implemented is in xUnit.net v2, and is related to the new runner infrastructure (in particular, `ITestFramework` and its two related interfaces `ITestFrameworkDiscoverer` and `ITestFrameworkExecutor`).

To specify a new test framework for an assembly, you use an assembly level attribute on the test assembly:

```
[assembly: TestFramework("MyNamespace.MyTestFramework", "MyTestFrameworkAssembly")]
```